# Using app.Environment in HttpRequestInterceptor?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-middleware, hotchocolate, aspnetcore-environment

In `Program.cs` I can use

```
app.Environment.IsDevelopment()
```

Now I have a custom `HttpRequestInterceptor : DefaultHttpRequestInterceptor` with a method

```
public override ValueTask OnCreateAsync(HttpContext context,
IRequestExecutor requestExecutor, IQueryRequestBuilder requestBuilder,
CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

How can I get access to `app.Environment.IsDevelopment()` in that method? (I want to set some kind of faked authentication during development)

Comment: You should probably be able to inject the IWebHostEnvironment in the constructor of the HttpRequestInterceptor.

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine. Please post as answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the `IWebHostEnvironment` through the constructor of the `HttpRequestInterceptor` and perform your `IsDevelopment` check on that injected instance.